# Replace fan speed controller with Dimmer switch

Tags: dimmer-switch

I replaced a fan with a light fixture and the fan used a fan speed controller.  It has two red wires going to two black wires. How would I replace the speed controller with a single pole dimmer?[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: Lucky for you it should be as easy as just connect the two wires from the SP dimmer to the two wires coming out of the wall...

Comment: Photo added.  There is the supply cable, cable going to new light and cable for the three way switch that is in the same box. The closest red wire from fan controller is wired with a pigtail hot from the switch.   Not sure what the other red wire is connected to

Comment: What make and model is the dimmer?

Comment: Was looking at the Lutron Skylark model ctcl-150h-wh.  It has two black and one ground.   Sounds like I can just swap out the two red for black and connect the ground (green) to the existing ground nut?  Does it matter which black goes where?

Comment: If I wanted to keep the fan control knob and just use that to turn the light on can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The color (as long as it isn't white, green, or bare) doesn't matter; they're just pig-tails on switch legs. You're good to go here with a direct swap out and arbitrarily connecting the wires to the new device (assuming it doesn't have a neutral contact. If it does it probably matters which contact has incoming power. Read the directions ;).

Make sure those nuts are still snug after you're done.

Comment: I'd eliminate the pig tail on the right; that black wire looks long enough. Looks like it could be *two* pig tails on the right. That doesn't pass muster for me. Make it one (each) or none.

Answer (score 0):

You did not state what type of light fixture you replaced the fan with. So, you should be aware that the spec on the Lutron Skylark model ctcl-150h-wh states:

"Minimum load-

Incandescent/Halogen: 10 Watts 
LED: 1 SSL7A compliant lamp unless stated otherwise in the Lutron compatible bulb list at www.lutron.com/dimcflled"

Most likely this won't be an issue for you, but just in case...

Comment: The light fixture has 5 lights. We have 40w/4.5w bulbs. Is the minimum load for all bulbs combined? I checked and the bulbs are on the compatibility list for the dimmee

Comment: That is fine. The min load would be all 5 bulbs--so you are more than double the minimum.